# .htaccess Rewrite Questions

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect a dynamic url to another url, with the dynamic portion intact, for example:

http://www.mydomain.com/VARHome.aspx?var=32

needs to redirect to:

To: http://www.otherdomain.com/VARHome.aspx?var=32

The value after "var=" is dynamic, it can be any number.

This needs to be done via .htaccess.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.otherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]` or something along those lines should do the job.

Edit: Maybe something like

```
RewriteRule ^VARHome.aspx?var=(.*)?$ http://www.otherdomain.org/VARHome.aspx?var=$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That does a blanket redirect from mydomain to otherdomain, I only want to redirect urls with /VARHome.aspx?var= to otherdomain.com, so http://www.mydomain.com/VARHome.aspx?var=32 needs to redirect to http://www.otherdomain.com/VARHome.aspx?var=32, but mydomain.com/test.html does not redirect to otherdomain.com/test.html

Comment: @adrian collins Added another version, perhaps this is what you need.

Comment: @adrian collins I'm afraid I don't have any means available for testing these right now, so I can't be 100% sure, but I think the second one is somewhere close to what it should look like. Perhaps removing the question mark from `(.*)?`? Sorry I can't help you any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in mydomain.com, write in .htaccess

RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch 301 ^/VARHome.aspx?var=(.*)$ http://www.otherdomain.com/VARHome.aspx?var=$1

Comment: I only have access to otherdomain.com htaccess

Comment: Sorry, I meant the opposite, I placed that line in the mydomain.com htaccess file, unfortunately it did not work. The site is WP, so I am not sure if the line needs to be placed in a specific place in the WP generated .htaccess file.